# Angular wait for a loop with promises to execute before continuing with next code block

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to send data to an api endpoint but for some strange reason, which I can't figure out, the data doesn't get sent.

Below is the method but when you inspect the request.

```
  syncPatients(){  
    let patients = [];
    this.sqlite.create({name: 'criticare.db', location: 'default'})
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM patients where updated_at >= (?)',[this.settings.last_sync_time])
      .then((data) =>{
        if(data.rows.length > 0){
          //let patients = [];
          for(var i =0; i < data.rows.length; i++){
            var _patient = data.rows.item(i);
            //console.log(_patient);
            db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM wards WHERE id = (?)',[_patient.id])
            .then((ward_data)=>{
              if(ward_data.rows.length > 0){
                _patient.ward_id = ward_data.rows.item(0).online_ref;
                patients.push(JSON.stringify(_patient));
                //console.log(patients);
              }else{
                console.log("Ward not found");
              }              
            })            
          }//end of for loop
        }else{
          console.log('No patients to sync');
        }
      })
      .then(()=>{
          console.log(patients);         
          var headers = new Headers();
          headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
          headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+ this.settings.token);
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
          let postParams = { patients: JSON.stringify(patients) };
          console.log(patients);
          this.http.post(this.api_url+"/patients/sync", postParams, options).subscribe(data => {
            let response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            if(response.status == "Ok"){
              response.result.forEach(element =>{
                db.executeSql('UPDATE patients SET online_ref = (?), updated_at = (?) WHERE id = (?)',[element.online_id, this.getCurrentTime(), element.id]).then(() => {
                  console.log('Updated patient ' + element.id)
                }).catch(e =>{
                  console.log(e);
                })
              });
            }else{
              console.log("Error syncing patients");
            }
          }) //end of post
      })
    })

  }
```

The problem is in the last `.then()` I the console logs before and after i do the `let postParams = { patients: JSON.stringify(patients) };` show that `patients` has the right data but when you inspect the request, the pay load is

```
 {
  "patients": ""
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

***Update***
Turns out as @orodan and @jc-ford suggested, the problem was with the http post being executed before some promises resolving. I have refactored the code with their suggestions, introduce async and await to below and it works great now.

```
 syncPatients(){
  let patients = [];
  this.sqlite.create({name: 'criticare.db', location: 'default'})
  .then((db:SQLiteObject) => {
    db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM patients where updated_at >= (?)',[this.settings.last_sync_time])
    .then((data) =>{
      if(data.rows.length > 0){
        for(var i =0; i < data.rows.length; i++){
          patients.push(data.rows.item(i));           
        }
      }
      else{
        console.log('No patients to sync');
      }
      return patients;
    })
    .then(async (patients)=>{
      const patientsPromises = patients.map(async (patient) =>{
        const data = await db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM wards WHERE id = (?)',[patient.id])
         patient.ward_id = data.rows.item(0).online_ref
      })
      // new patients
      let all_promises = await Promise.all(patientsPromises);
      console.log(patients);
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+ this.settings.token);
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let postParams = { patients: JSON.stringify(patients) };
      this.http.post(this.api_url+"/patients/sync", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        let response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        if(response.status == "Ok"){
          this.sqlite.create({name: 'criticare.db', location: 'default'})
          .then((db:SQLiteObject) =>{
            response.result.forEach(element =>{
              db.executeSql('UPDATE patients SET online_ref = (?), updated_at = (?) WHERE id = (?)',[element.online_id, this.getCurrentTime(), element.id])
              .then(() => {
                console.log('Updated patient ' + element.id)
              })
              .catch(e =>{
                console.log(e);
              })
            });
          })

        }else{
          console.log("Error syncing patients");
        }
      }) //end of subscribe
    })
  }) 
 }
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you console.log postParams ?

Comment: Yes. It is empty! Just has ```{ "patients": ""}``` Any idea why? It looks like the ```JSON.stringify(patients)``` never results into anything!

Comment: Ok and have you tried to console.log JSON.stringify(patients) ^^ ? Maybe it failed and you didn't catch the error ?

Comment: ```JSON.stringify(patients)``` returns ```[]```. Even when I replace the whole ```postParams``` with just ```patients```, all I get is ```[]``` which I find strange because just after that, when you ```console.log(patients)``` it isn't empty!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in your promises. See my comments below.

```
 syncPatients(){  
    let patients = [];
    this.sqlite.create({name: 'criticare.db', location: 'default'})
    .then((db: SQLiteObject) =>{
      db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM patients where updated_at >= (?)',[this.settings.last_sync_time])
      .then((data) =>{
        if(data.rows.length > 0){
          //let patients = [];
          for(var i =0; i < data.rows.length; i++){
            var _patient = data.rows.item(i);
            //console.log(_patient);


            //You're kicking off an asynchronous process here, but not chaining
            //its promise to the current promise.

            db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM wards WHERE id = (?)',[_patient.id])
            .then((ward_data)=>{
              if(ward_data.rows.length > 0){
                _patient.ward_id = ward_data.rows.item(0).online_ref;
                patients.push(JSON.stringify(_patient));
                //console.log(patients);
              }else{
                console.log("Ward not found");
              }              
            })            
          }//end of for loop
        }else{
          console.log('No patients to sync');
        }
      })
      .then(()=>{

          //This part executes before the executeSql() promises above return
          //so the patients.push() above hasn't happened yet.

          console.log(patients);         
          var headers = new Headers();
          headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
          headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+ this.settings.token);
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
          let postParams = { patients: JSON.stringify(patients) };
          console.log(patients);
          this.http.post(this.api_url+"/patients/sync", postParams, options).subscribe(data => {
            let response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
            if(response.status == "Ok"){
              response.result.forEach(element =>{
                db.executeSql('UPDATE patients SET online_ref = (?), updated_at = (?) WHERE id = (?)',[element.online_id, this.getCurrentTime(), element.id]).then(() => {
                  console.log('Updated patient ' + element.id)
                }).catch(e =>{
                  console.log(e);
                })
              });
            }else{
              console.log("Error syncing patients");
            }
          }) //end of post
      })
    })

  }
```

Try returning the `executeSql()` promises wrapped in `$q.all()` (or I think `Promise.all()` if you're in the Angular 2+ world) from your first `.then()` to chain the promises together. I think they work largely the same, but here are links to the docs for each.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Thanks for the hints... I had imagined the ```then()``` that has the http post happens after everything before it has executed. Would you be kind enough to show me how $q.all() would work with my example or how I can wait to execute the post until everything else has executed?

Comment: If you're in the AngularJS world `$q.all()` will take an array of promises and give you a new promise that resolves when all of the promises in the array have resolved. If you're in the Angular 2+ world, I think you have to use the ES6 promise functionality which I think is `Promise.all()` which also takes an array of promises.

Answer (score 1):

You have an asynchronous problem here : you don't wait for your wards data to be here before making your http call.

Because you have to wait for multiple calls to your db before making your http request, I would advice to use Promise.all which allow you to wait for the end of all promises passed as an array parameter before continuing something.
It would look like something like that :

```
const dbCalls = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
    const _patient = data.rows.item(i);
    dbCall = db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM wards WHERE id = (?)',[_patient.id]);
}

Promise.all(dbCalls)
   .then(dbResults => {
      dbResults.forEach(ward_data => {
          if (ward_data.rows.length > 0) {
             _patient.ward_id = ward_data.rows.item(0).online_ref;
             patients.push(JSON.stringify(_patient));
           } else {
             console.log("Ward not found");
           }
      });

      console.log(patients);         
      var headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
      headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+ this.settings.token);
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let postParams = { patients: JSON.stringify(patients) };
      console.log(patients);
      this.http.post(this.api_url+"/patients/sync", postParams, options).subscribe(data => {
        let response = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        if(response.status == "Ok"){
          response.result.forEach(element =>{
            db.executeSql('UPDATE patients SET online_ref = (?), updated_at = (?) WHERE id = (?)',[element.online_id, this.getCurrentTime(), element.id]).then(() => {
              console.log('Updated patient ' + element.id)
            }).catch(e =>{
              console.log(e);
            })
          });
        }else{
          console.log("Error syncing patients");
        }
      }) //end of post
  })
```

And as to why you saw your patients while debugging : don't trust console.log. Because you had an asynchronous problem, at some point in time, your db calls finished and your patients were populated. The console.log gave you the "latest version" of your patients, but at the moment you were trying to do your http call, they were not here yet ^^

PS : I used some ES6 syntax in my example, it you can't juste replace arrow functions with "function" and any const and let with "var".